# C/C++ file before preprocessing

Tags: c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Is it possible to look at a c/c++ file before preprocessing? Or rather after just a half-hearted pre-processing? Basically there is a

```
#define <commonly_used_word> 0
```

in a third party library header and I want to figure out where it is. So basically, I just want the compiler to include all the headers but not the the preprocessor as such.

Comment: grep <commonly_used_word> <headerFile1> [<headerFile2>]

Comment: `find /usr/include -name '*.h' | xargs grep -P '^#define <commonword>'`?

Comment: Well it's more of a vendor library with several places where this is written... I want to zero in on the specific header file causing this problem. (Yes it's a terrible library to work with)...

Comment: gcc has options to print the inclusion chain for a source file. That might help.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti Can you point me to a resource that explains how to print the inclusion chain?

Comment: @eq-: `find /usr/include -name '*.h' -exec grep -P '^#define <commonword>' {} +`. Please don't abuse `xargs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original source file *is* file before preprocessing.

It sounds like you want your `#include` directives processed, yet you want to keep macros non-substituted. Both actions are carried out by the preprocessor.

In general case it is impossible, since in C and C++ it is legal to use macros as include file names, as in

```
#define INCLUDE_FILE "stdio.h"
#include INCLUDE_FILE
```

Achieving what you want would require a preprocessor specifically designed to satisfy your request. I, for one, don't know of any such preprocessor implementation.

If you want to find where a specific macro is defined, you might try the following trick: define your own macro with the same name *before* including any headers, and start compilation. The compiler (the preprocessor) should complain about macro redefinition when it encounters the library definition of the same macro and point out its location to you.

Comment: Makes sense... +1. 
Would it be possible to just print out the inclusion chain then as nicola musatti suggest?

Comment: Brilliant! Redefining the macro pinpointed it exactly! Thanks.

Comment: @AndreyT What you mean by *impossible*? He needs to run the preprocessor on some file and get the preprocessed file, which is absolutely possible as mentioned in other responses.

Comment: @behnam: I'm not sure what you mean. Running full preprocessor will eliminate all `#define` statements from the translation unit. This will completely defeat the purpose of what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @AndreyT: Oh, you're right. I misunderstood the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are GCC-specific `-M` and `-MM` options:

> To list absolute paths of include files, use -M
>
> Instead of outputting the result of preprocessing, output a rule
>   suitable for make describing the dependencies of the main source file.
>   The preprocessor outputs one make rule containing the object file name
>   for that source file, a colon, and the names of all the included
>   files, including those coming from -include or -imacros command line
>   options. gcc  -M test.c
>
> If you dont want the system includes like
>   `#include <stdio.h>`, 
>   then use -MM Like -M but do not mention header files that are found in
>   system header directories, nor header files that are included,
>   directly or indirectly, from such a header. gcc  -MM test.c

That could significantly narrow down the search area.

http://www.math-linux.com/spip.php?article263

Answer (score 1):

You can tell `cpp` to generate the list of included files using `-M` option:

```
$ cpp -M a.c
a.o: a.c /usr/include/stdio.h /usr/include/features.h \
 /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h \
 /usr/include/gnu/stubs.h /usr/include/gnu/stubs-64.h \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.1/include/stddef.h \
 /usr/include/bits/types.h /usr/include/bits/typesizes.h \
 /usr/include/libio.h /usr/include/_G_config.h /usr/include/wchar.h \
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.1/include/stdarg.h \
 /usr/include/bits/stdio_lim.h /usr/include/bits/sys_errlist.h
```

It gives you a Makefile rule format but you could ignore that and use with any other command.

For example, you can grep for the symbol (here I'm ignoring stderr because of `\` and `a.o:` not being a real file names -- laziness):

```
$ grep '#\s*define\s*BUFSIZ' $(cpp -M a.c) 2>/dev/null
/usr/include/stdio.h:# define BUFSIZ _IO_BUFSIZ
```

You can also use a program like `ctags` to find the symbol for you:

```
$ ctags $(cpp -M a.c)
...
$ grep BUFSIZ tags 
BUFSIZ  /usr/include/stdio.h    128;"   d
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know which header files contain the definition you're looking for, e.g by using find and grep as suggested, you may be able to pinpoint which one is affecting the current source file by getting gcc to print the header inclusion tree. As described in gcc's [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options), you can achieve this by using the -H option, possibly combined with -MG to eliminate normal processing.